# Qt: pjsip linking problems

Tags: c++, linux, qt, sip, pjsip

I am trying to write a softphone using qt. And many forums and resources, including stackoverflow, suggest to use pjsip libraries. So I decided to follow this advice and use it.
First, to be clear about my post here, my OS is linux (KUbuntu to be percise), and I am using Qt 5.4.1 and Qt Creator 3.3.2.

Also, I built pjsip static libraries using instructions on their website here: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Autoconf.

And I have some troubles linking pjsip static libraries using qt. I've searched about this problem and didn't find the answer neither on this site nor anywhere. There are some topics on the forums but no one gives an answer to it.

Here is my qt .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick widgets

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

INCLUDEPATH += $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/pjsip_headers

LIBS += -L$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/pjsip_libs

linux-g++-64:LIBS += -lpjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lpjsip-ua-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu\
                     -lpjsip-simple-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lpjsip-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lpjmedia-codec-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lpjmedia-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lpjmedia-codec-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lpjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lpjmedia-videodev-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lpjnath-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lpjlib-util-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lpj-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lportaudio-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lgsmcodec-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lilbccodec-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lspeex-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lresample-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lsrtp-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lg7221codec-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu \
                     -lopenh264 \
                     -lpjsua2-x86_64-unknown-linux.gnu 

QML_IMPORT_PATH =

include(deployment.pri)
```

**And here is the problem: when I try to build my project with this .pro file above, everything is OK until i try to use some function or an object of any class in this library. And if I do so, I get many undefined reference errors.**

Pjsip manual says only about how to build your own application with this library by using GNU tools here: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting_Started_Using. But it involves editing Makefile, which is autogenerated by qmake in qt.

I just stuck with this problem and I don't know what else I can do about it. I read about linking order of this library while including it in your qt .pro file, but I tried many combinations and it didn't help.
Also, I read that it might be necessary to use QMAKE variables to set CFLAGS and LDFLAGS in qt .pro file according to pjsip instructions of how to build your own application using GNU tools.
And I even downloaded qt projects, which use pjsip libraries, for example, QjSimple, but I didn't find anything new in their qt .pro file settings.

Here is their qt .pro file:

```
DEFINES -= UNICODE
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = QjSimple
QT += core \
      gui \
      xml \
      network
HEADERS += buddy.h \
           PjCallback.h \
           accountdialog.h \
           debugdialog.h \
           addbuddydialog.h \
           imwidget.h \
           qjsimple.h
SOURCES += buddy.cpp \
           PjCallback.cpp \
           accountdialog.cpp \
           debugdialog.cpp \
           addbuddydialog.cpp \
           imwidget.cpp \
           main.cpp \
           qjsimple.cpp
FORMS += accountdialog.ui \
         debugdialog.ui \
         addbuddydialog.ui \
         imwidget.ui \
         qjsimple.ui
RESOURCES += icons.qrc
win32-g++:RC_FILE = appicon.rc
INCLUDEPATH += ../pjproject-1.8.10/pjlib/include \
               ../pjproject-1.8.10/pjlib-util/include \
               ../pjproject-1.8.10/pjnath/include \
               ../pjproject-1.8.10/pjmedia/include \
               ../pjproject-1.8.10/pjsip/include
LIBS += -L../pjproject-1.8.10/pjlib/lib \
        -L../pjproject-1.8.10/pjlib-util/lib \
        -L../pjproject-1.8.10/pjnath/lib \
        -L../pjproject-1.8.10/pjmedia/lib \
        -L../pjproject-1.8.10/pjsip/lib \
        -L../pjproject-1.8.10/third_party/lib

# INCLUDEPATH += ../pjproject-1.5.5/pjlib/include \
# ../pjproject-1.5.5/pjlib-util/include \
# ../pjproject-1.5.5/pjnath/include \
# ../pjproject-1.5.5/pjmedia/include \
# ../pjproject-1.5.5/pjsip/include
# LIBS += -L../pjproject-1.5.5/pjlib/lib \
# -L../pjproject-1.5.5/pjlib-util/lib \
# -L../pjproject-1.5.5/pjnath/lib \
# -L../pjproject-1.5.5/pjmedia/lib \
# -L../pjproject-1.5.5/pjsip/lib \
# -L../pjproject-1.5.5/third_party/lib
# INCLUDEPATH += ../pjproject-1.4/pjlib/include \
# ../pjproject-1.4/pjlib-util/include \
# ../pjproject-1.4/pjnath/include \
# ../pjproject-1.4/pjmedia/include \
# ../pjproject-1.4/pjsip/include
# LIBS += -L../pjproject-1.4/pjlib/lib \
# -L../pjproject-1.4/pjlib-util/lib \
# -L../pjproject-1.4/pjnath/lib \
# -L../pjproject-1.4/pjmedia/lib \
# -L../pjproject-1.4/pjsip/lib \
# -L../pjproject-1.4/third_party/lib
# win32-g++:LIBS += -L../openssl-0.9.8g
win32-g++:LIBS += -L../OpenSSL/lib/mingw
win32-g++:LIBS += -lpjsua-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lpjsip-ua-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lpjsip-simple-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lpjsip-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lpjmedia-codec-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lpjmedia-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lpjmedia-codec-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lpjmedia-audiodev-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lpjnath-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lpjlib-util-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lpj-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lportaudio-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lgsmcodec-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lilbccodec-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lspeex-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lresample-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lmilenage-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lsrtp-i686-pc-mingw32 \
                  -lm \
                  -lwinmm \
                  -lole32 \
                  -lws2_32 \
                  -lwsock32 \
                  -lssl \
                  -lcrypto \
                  -lgdi32
linux-g++:LIBS += -lpjsua-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lpjsip-ua-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lpjsip-simple-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lpjsip-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lpjmedia-codec-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lpjmedia-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lpjmedia-codec-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lpjmedia-audiodev-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lpjnath-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lpjlib-util-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lpj-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lportaudio-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lgsmcodec-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lilbccodec-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lspeex-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lresample-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lmilenage-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lsrtp-i686-pc-linux-gnu \
                  -lm \
                  -lpthread \
                  -lssl \
                  -lasound \
                  -luuid
linux-g++-64:LIBS += -lpjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lpjsip-ua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lpjsip-simple-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lpjsip-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lpjmedia-codec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lpjmedia-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lpjmedia-codec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lpjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lpjnath-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lpjlib-util-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lpj-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lportaudio-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lgsmcodec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lilbccodec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lspeex-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lresample-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lmilenage-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lsrtp-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
                     -lm \
                     -lpthread \
                     -lssl \
                     -lasound \
                     -luuid
macx-g++:LIBS += -lpjsua-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lpjsip-ua-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lpjsip-simple-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lpjsip-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lpjmedia-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lpjmedia-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lpjmedia-codec-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lpjmedia-audiodev-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lpjnath-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lpjlib-util-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lpj-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lportaudio-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lgsmcodec-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lilbccodec-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lspeex-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lresample-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lmilenage-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lsrtp-i386-apple-darwin9.7.1 \
                 -lm \
                 -lpthread \
                 -lssl \
                 -lcrypto \
                 -framework \
                 CoreAudio \
                 -framework \
                 AudioToolbox \
                 -framework \
                 AudioUnit
OTHER_FILES += Changelog
```

There is nothing new in their .pro file. 
So I just don't know where to find the solution. I hope I gave enough information. And as I mentioned above, I didn't find anyting useful about this problem.

Maybe there is another way to build a softphone by using qt, but as I found out pjsip library is one of the best decisions to do that. Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this problem somehow eventually?